# Simplify table pagination ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pagination

newbie here. I need some help to simplify my pagination table. This is my current pagination.
[image]

But I want to make like this.

[image]

It is possible to make it with minor changes on my code?

Here I attach my pagination code for reference.

**posts.php**

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo "<h1>404 Page Not found!</h1>";
    exit;
}

require 'db_connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $page_num = filter_var($_POST['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,[
        'options' => [
            'default' => 1,
            'min_range' => 1
        ]
    ]); 
    
} else { $page_num = 1; }

$page_limit = 5;
$page_offset = $page_limit * ($page_num - 1);

function showPosts($conn, $current_page_num, $page_limit, $page_offset){
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $page_limit OFFSET $page_offset");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
            echo '<li><b>'.$row['firstname']." / ".$row['lastname'].'</b><p>'.$row['email'].'</p></li>';
        }
        $total_posts = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users"));
        $total_page = ceil($total_posts / $page_limit);
        $next_page = $current_page_num+1; 
        $prev_page = $current_page_num-1; 
        
       echo "<li>";
        if($current_page_num > 1) {
           echo '<a href="'.$prev_page.'" class="page_link">Prev</a>';
        }
        for($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) {
            if($i == $current_page_num){
                echo '<a href="'.$i.'" class="page_link active_page">'.$i.'</a>';
            }else{
                echo '<a href="'.$i.'" class="page_link">'.$i.'</a>';
            }
            
        }
        if($total_page+1 != $next_page) {
           echo '<a href="'.$next_page.'" class="page_link">Next</a>';
        }
        echo "</li>";
    } else { echo "No Data found !"; }
}
showPosts($conn, $page_num, $page_limit, $page_offset);
?>
```

Comment: refer this link hope it will helps you :-)

https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/197705-how-do-you-limit-pagination-linksnumbers/

Comment: This is a (CSS) styling question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Why?

Comment: It's not about css boss @FunkFortyNiner. Yeah I know ui for 2nd image is much better than 1st image. But I dont care about that css style. If u see the 1st image, at pagination show all the pages and 2nd image, pagination show only certain pages then hide the rest.

Comment: Ok sorry. I misunderstood the question.